# How to update less variable from JS file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gulp, less

-- random.less --

@selectedValue: "20";

height: @selectedValue;

-- random.js --

I would like to update `@selectedValue` as below

```
if (temperature > 25) @selectedValue = 400;
else
@selectedValue = 20;
```

===>

Can we achieve something like this with less/webpack/gulp ?

Comment: You might be interested in libraries such as styled-components, radium or glamorous. Those are JS to CSS compilers which work at runtime, removing the need of CSS files.

Comment: @LaurentDeCant Thanks for the guide. I have achieved using gulp. gulp-inject have some nice feature, so I used them. -Thanks